# How to check a var for null value?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, petapoco

I am using PetaPoco Micro-ORM with C# 4.0.

The code below retrieves a single row from the database:

```
var result = db.SingleOrDefault<TdUsers>(getUserQuery);
```

I would like to check whether or not the result contains any rows, and whether is null. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
if (result == null || result.Count() == 0) {
    // Checks whether the entire result is null OR
    // contains no resulting records.
}
```

I think the problem is not in your check for `null`, because linq is lazy loading. Your error is in using the expression `db.SingleOrDefault<TdUsers>(getUserQuery);`.

`.Single<T>(expression)` does not return null - it errors if the result returns no values. 
`.SingleOrDefault<T>(expression)`, however, returns a null value if the expression results in no values - and therefore is best combined with an `if (result == null)` type check, as you're using here.

Comment: Tried result != null, but it displays "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: @RPK - can you post your code in the question then. This should work.

Comment: or `!result.Any()` :)

Answer (score 5):

```
var result = db.SingleOrDefault<TdUsers>(getUserQuery);
```

> In above code SingleOrDefault will return null vale or the specified
>   generic type(it's known on runtime).

Inorder to check whether the returned values is null or not you can simply use

```
if(result!=null)
{
//do your code stuff 
}
else
{
//stuff do be done in case where result==null
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
result.ToList() // Convert result to a list

if (result.Any()) {
   // result is not null
}
```

Comment: NO result==null wont be false always.. what do you think is the default value of any reference type?

Comment: This approach won't work in every case, because `result` could be null, at which point you will get a `NullReferenceException` thrown when `.ToList()` or `.Any()` are called.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var v = result.ToList();
```

now check

```
if (v is not null)
{

}
else if (v.Count()>0)
{


}
```

Comment: See my comment to the answer above.