# Check if var da/dtCounts has been assigned before doing anything

Tags: c#

How would I check if `da` and `dtCounts` is null before assigning it to a new object?

```
        var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        var dtCounts = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dtCounts);
```

Comment: `da` will not be null if you construct it... same with `dtCounts`..

Comment: @grmbl - what do you mean?

Comment: Disregard my comment above.You could check for the return value of da.Fill(dtCounts) because it returns a int.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check a var for null value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753661/how-to-check-a-var-for-null-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `var` in this scenario. Here's a simple example...

```
MySqlDataAdapter da;
DataTable dtCounts;

// Other code here...

if (da == null)
    da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

if (dtCounts == null)
    dtCounts = new DataTable();

da.Fill(dtCounts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that is using the C# Null-coalescing Operator ?? 
It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.
So your code can look like:

```
MySqlDataAdapter da;
DataTable dtCounts;

// Other code here...

da = da ?? new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
dtCounts = dtCounts ?? new DateTable();

da.Fill(dtCounts);
```